# How to use rails select_tag to get child element as a dropdown text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I have this code:

```
= select_tag "order", options_from_collection_for_select(Order.where(finished: false), "id", Order.find(id).table.title)
```

but it returns

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for #<#<Class:0x007f76b9f64370>:0x007f76b8a3a760>
```

The error adresses `Order.find(id).table.title` part. How could I fix it to make it work?

Comment: The error is due to this `Order.find(id).table.title` What are you trying actually?

Comment: @Pavan I'm trying to get the title of the table that is the parent for the particular `Order`

Comment: Try `Order.find(params[:id]).table.title`

Comment: @Pavan there isn't a `GET` request being made so no `param` available. Just need to loop through all the `Order` fields and show the title of the table for that order.

Comment: Try `Order.all.collect{ |o| o.table.title }`

Comment: @Pavan that gives `undefined method 'collect' for #<Class:0x007f76b9718798>`

Comment: I just changed. Check and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about if you add following method in order.rb

```
def table_title
 self.table.title
end
```

and use it like this.

```
 = select_tag "order", options_from_collection_for_select(Order.where(finished: false), "id", "table_title")
```